# How to turn API information into a dictionary

Tags: api, dictionary, twitter, bots, ascii

I'm trying to create a Twitter bot that gives daily news about random subjects.

I want to import those daily news from Mediastack and it works pretty well, but I receive something like that (I'm French, that's why the article is in French and there is those strange characters):

```
Article(author=None, title='La pand�mie motive les voleurs: Une nette hausse
des escroqueries financi�res constat�e', description='L�instance de m�diation
des banques suisses a trait� 2175 nouveaux cas en 2020, ce qui repr�sente une
hausse de 8% par rapport � l�ann�e pr�c�dente.', url='https://www.tdg.ch/une-
nette-hausse-des-escroqueries-financieres-constatee-333483840132', 
image='https://cdn.unitycms.io/image/ocroped/400,400,1000,1000,0,0/s7bDqn27jGQ/FU0
Tdt5Oqhp9VzkeyvqdPJ.jpg', category='general', language='fr', country='ch', 
published_at='2021-07-01T12:17:02+00:00', source='Tribune de Geneve')
```

I would like to put all this informations into a dict so I can use what I need. I would also like to change the strange characters into the letters with accents (like "é") they should be.

Comment: You haven't specified how you were accessing the API, or in what language, so it would have been very difficult for anyone to give you a useful answer. Now you have answered it to say that you are using a different API which doesn't help as we don't know what API you have used or how you are using it...

Answer (score 0):

I changed the API I was using and I directly get a dict to the request.
Thanks!